# for each XSLT with twin nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML file that has multiple child nodes of the same name. When I run a `for-each` loop to transform the XML markup only the first of each twin node is printed. Do I need to used a nested loop? If so how because I've tried that resulting in error. Here is my XSLT syntax:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cdcatalog.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
      <h2>CD Catalog</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Band</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Rating</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/band">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="cd/title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="cd/rating"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="cd/yearReleased"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="cd/dateAcquired"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

And here is my XML markup; as you can see, each band has multiple CDs but only the first CD of each band is being printed:

```
    <catalog>

      <band>
        <name>Aloha</name>
        <based>Cleveland, OH</based>
        <active>true</active>
        <cd>
          <title>That's Your Fire</title>
          <label>Polyvinyl</label>
          <numTracks>10</numTracks>
          <rating>9</rating>
          <yearReleased>2000</yearReleased>
          <dateAcquired>12/25/02</dateAcquired>
        </cd>
        <cd>
          <title>Sugar</title>
          <label>Polyvinyl</label>
          <numTracks>10</numTracks>
          <rating>9</rating>
          <yearReleased>2002</yearReleased>
          <dateAcquired>12/25/07</dateAcquired>
        </cd>
      </band>

    </catalog>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @keshlam, you may need to refresh, I modified my example.

Comment: The symptoms suggest you are using XSLT 1.0. If that's the case, PLEASE SAY SO. The two versions of XSLT are very different, and it makes life harder for people answering questions if you give no clue as to which version you are using.

Comment: XML 1.0 is what my documents all say in the headers, does this answer your question?

Comment: Oh dear no. The version of XML and the version of XSLT are completely unrelated. If you're using XSLT 1.0 and didn't know that 2.0 existed, then you have been working in the dark with a blindfold. There are some environments where 2.0 isn't supported, so you may be stuck with it, but don't stick with it out of ignorance, please! 2.0 will double your productivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a row for each *band*, instead of for each *cd*. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cdcatalog.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>CD Catalog</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Band</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/band/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="yearReleased"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="dateAcquired"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That should do it. Note too that `xsl:value-of` is defined to return only the value of the first result matching the select, which explains the results you were seeing from the broken version. Also, as a general rule, you should start thinking about rule-driven stylesheets and `xsl:apply-templates` rather than `xsl:for-each` -- it doesn't matter in this case, but it will when you're doing more complicated tasks.